# Proving Lindenbaum's Theorem via the ultrafilter theorem

Tags: general-topology, logic, first-order-logic, filters

Consider a first-order language $L$. **Lindenbaum's Theorem** states that if $S$ is a consistent set of $L$-sentences. Then there is a complete and consistent set $S^{*}$ of $L$-sentences such that $S\subseteq S^{*}$.

I am learning about filters/ultrafilters and I am looking for someone to point me in the right direction to deduce Lindenbaum's Theorem from the ultrafilter theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some things to check:

- Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of all $L$-sentences. Write $\varphi\equiv \psi$ when sentences $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are logically equivalent. Then $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{S}/{\equiv}$ has the structure of a Boolean algebra, called the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra.
- A filter on the Boolean algebra $\mathcal{B}$ is the same thing as an $L$-theory (a set of $L$-sentences) which is closed under logical consequence.
- A filter is proper if and only if the corresponding $L$-theory is consistent.
- A filter is an ultrafilter if and only if the corresponding $L$-theory is complete and consistent.

Once you've internalized the above correspondences, the equivalence between the ultrafilter theorem and Lindenbaum's theorem is immediate. Extending a filter to an ultrafilter is the same thing as extending a consistent theory to a consistent complete theory.

In more detail: Given a consistent $L$-theory $T$, form the filter $F\subseteq \mathcal{B}$ corresponding to the set of all logical consequences of $T$. This is a proper filter since $T$ is consistent. Then use the ultrafilter theorem to extend $F$ to an ultrafilter $U$. Finally, let $T^*$ be the theory corresponding to $U$. We have $T\subseteq T^*$, and $T^*$ is a complete consistent $L$-theory.

Comment: Much appreciated! I spent time appropriately internalizing the points you made, and I was able to work out the proof without looking at your details. Indeed, I understand now clearly how Lindenbaum's Theorem is equivalent to the statement that every filter on the Lindenbaum algebra can be extended to an ultrafilter. Thank you for taking the time to write the answer.

Comment: If in addition $S$ is finitely satisfiable, then would $S^{*}$ be finitely satisfiable as well?

Comment: @John By the completeness theorem, "finitely satisfiable" and "consistent" are equivalent. If you want to avoid the completeness theorem, there are actually two versions of the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra. The syntactic version consists of sentences modulo provable equivalence, a filter is a theory closed under provable entailment ($\vdash$), and a proper filter corresponds to a consistent theory (one that does not prove a contradiction).

Comment: The semantic version consists of sentences modulo semantic equivalence (having the same models), a filter is a theory closed under semantic entailment ($\models$), and a propert filter corresponds to a finitely satisfiable theory.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I see, $S^{*}\vDash A\Rightarrow A\in S^{*}$ because $S^{*}\vDash A$ means there is a finite $\{A_{i}\}\subseteq S^{*}$ satisfying $A$ and if $A\notin S^{*}$ then $\neg A\in S^{*}$ (as $S^{*}$ is complete) and then the class of $\wedge_{i}A_{i}\wedge \neg A$, which is empty, would be in the ultrafilter used to define $S^{*}$. So $S^{*}$ is closed under semantic entailment and from this I can esdily show $S^{*}$ is finitely satisfiable.

Comment: By the way, understanding the syntax\semantics distinction properly (at least properly enough so far) has become a major aha moment in my learning of logic.